# Is it possible to use autocomplete across different CSS files in VSCode?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I'm using React, and in the file structure, I've defined a global CSS where I apply a reset and basic body styles, and within the root, I define some variables. I apply this CSS in the `main.jsx` file, which serves as the parent component for the entire project. I'm having issues using autocomplete to get the names of these variables in other CSS files in the project.

For example, I have the `Header.jsx` component within the components folder and its style file `Header.module.css`. In this file, I can't use autocomplete with the variable names from the globals.css file.

I've tried using the HTML CSS Support extension by ecmel, and it didn't work.

Comment: what if you import global file into the other file?